# How to separate between two icon in collapse jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a nested bootstrap collapse and it works but when i click to the second collapse the icon of the first collapse works too at same time so i think that the method jQuery have the same id or the same class i didn't know how to modify it to separate between the two icon of collapse.

Here is my code:

```js
//colapse avec circle

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_aarrow").text('remove_circle_outline');
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_aarrow").text('add_circle_outline');
});

//colapse avec expand

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_arrow").text('expand_less');
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_arrow").text('expand_more');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" id="Professions" style="border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="mdc-list-item" style="width:100%;margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Professionsliberales" style="cursor:pointer">
                <span class="user" style="font-weight:bold">Professions libérales</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="col-md-1 chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Professionsliberales" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
                <i class="Professionsliberales_arrow material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;">
                        expand_more
                        </i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Professionsliberales" class="collapse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#architect" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              <a class="mdc-list-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="display: block;height:100%;cursor:pointer;">
                <i class="architect_aarrow material-icons" style="margin-right:10px">
                     add_circle_outline
                     </i>Architectes, Ingénieurs et Techniciens
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="architect" style="margin-left:20px">
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="CPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                     Complémentaire forfait
                     </a>
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PLACPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                     Plafonds complémentaire
                     </a>
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="IDAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                     Invalidité décès
                     </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my problem is when i click to the second collapse with the circle icon i see also the expand icon works at same time and that is not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all elements are `collapse` items and they are nested, they are both responding to the event because the event is bubbling up. With event bubbling, after the element receiving the event handles it, it passes the event to the parent element and so forth, until it is stopped or reaches the top element. Since the parent is also responding to `show.bs.collapse` events, it toggles, too.

Event bubbling is how Delegation works, you set a handler on a parent element *in behalf* of some of the children, reducing the number of events that you have to attach to the document and allowing the event to work on 'live' elements without having to attach the handler to every new element.

You can fix it by stopping the event in the inner element.

```js
//colapse avec circle

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_aarrow").text('remove_circle_outline');
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_aarrow").text('add_circle_outline');
});

//colapse avec expand

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  $("." + this.id + "_arrow").text('expand_less');
  evt.stopPropagation();
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  $("." + this.id + "_arrow").text('expand_more');
  evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" id="Professions" style="border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="mdc-list-item" style="width:100%;margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Professionsliberales" style="cursor:pointer">
                <span class="user" style="font-weight:bold">Professions libérales</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="col-md-1 chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Professionsliberales" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
                <i class="Professionsliberales_arrow material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;">
                        expand_more
                        </i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Professionsliberales" class="collapse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#architect" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              <a class="mdc-list-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="display: block;height:100%;cursor:pointer;">
                <i class="architect_aarrow material-icons" style="margin-right:10px">
                     add_circle_outline
                     </i>Architectes, Ingénieurs et Techniciens
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="architect" style="margin-left:20px">
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="CPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                     Complémentaire forfait
                     </a>
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PLACPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                     Plafonds complémentaire
                     </a>
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="IDAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                     Invalidité décès
                     </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you require event bubbling for other functionality in your page, you can use this other version without stopping the event:

```js
//colapse avec circle

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_aarrow").text('remove_circle_outline');
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $("." + this.id + "_aarrow").text('add_circle_outline');
});

//colapse avec expand

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target === evt.currentTarget) {
    $("." + this.id + "_arrow").text('expand_less');
  }
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target === evt.currentTarget) {
    $("." + this.id + "_arrow").text('expand_more');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" id="Professions" style="border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="mdc-list-item" style="width:100%;margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Professionsliberales" style="cursor:pointer">
                <span class="user" style="font-weight:bold">Professions libérales</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="col-md-1 chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Professionsliberales" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
                <i class="Professionsliberales_arrow material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;">
                            expand_more
                            </i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Professionsliberales" class="collapse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#architect" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
              <a class="mdc-list-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="display: block;height:100%;cursor:pointer;">
                <i class="architect_aarrow material-icons" style="margin-right:10px">
                         add_circle_outline
                         </i>Architectes, Ingénieurs et Techniciens
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="architect" style="margin-left:20px">
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="CPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                         Complémentaire forfait
                         </a>
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PLACPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                         Plafonds complémentaire
                         </a>
              <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="IDAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                         Invalidité décès
                         </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it is working just explain to me more what means the event is bubbling up ??

Comment: @mecab1995 sure thing